# Don't close the flag dialog when I'm in the middle of typing something in a textbox

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, flag-dialog

Sometimes when in the middle of writing a custom moderator flag, I click outside the flag dialog, for example because I want to get a link to one of the answers. This closes the flag dialog and forces me to write my message all over again, which is rather annoying. Therefore, I propose that clicking outside the flag dialog don't close it when I'm in the middle of typing something in a textbox (a custom moderator flag, a custom close reason, etc.).

Comment: This would also be great if it applied to the dupe dialog; sometimes I want to drag a related question's link into the URL field, but can't do that without closing the dialog.

Answer (score 4):

This should be implemented.

For one, the only ways to get out of it should only be `Esc` or clicking the `[X]` to ensure that you actually want to get out of the flag dialog box. This would also solve problems  that the one Nathan Tuggy mentioned:

> This would also be great if it applied to the dupe dialog; sometimes I want to drag a related question's link into the URL field, but can't do that without closing the dialog

Since you can't close the box via clicking outside, this wouldn't happen. Two, exiting the box while typing something should have a pop-up saying that your work will not be saved if you exit and if you click "Leave", you would actually leave the pop-up box. It should be similar to this one:

[image]