# Edits to the question make the flag dialog disappear (even when I'm typing a custom moderator message)

Tags: bug, user-interface, flag-dialog

Edits to the question reload the question and make the flag dialog disappear, even when I'm typing a custom moderator message.

This is annoying. I had to type the same message three times just now because the first two attempts the flag dialog was automatically closed due to edits.

Related: [Don't close the flag dialog when I'm in the middle of typing something in a textbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287377/166789) (this is about clicking outside the dialog, not having it disappear without user intervention).